# yeoman /app/bower_components missing

Tags: yeoman, bower

I'm using generator angular to create my project. I've deleted my app/bower_components directory by accident. Is it possible to restore it?

```
$ bower -v
1.2.8
$ bower intall
$ ls app
404.html     images      po          scripts  views
favicon.ico  index.html  robots.txt  styles
```

But there is no /app/bower_components. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing `.bowerrc` in project root folder, containing:

```
{
  "directory" : "scripts/components"
}
```